# Access sqlite database using QtableWidget c++ visual studio

Tags: c++, qtablewidget

I am new to stack overflow, I am using c++, I need to connect with my sqlite database which i am successfully accessing, Now I want to display that information (contents of tables from sqlite) into a table either Qtablewidget or Qtable view. I am novice to Qt. How should I do this?
How can I display information in QTablewidget in c++?

Comment: hi and welcome to SO, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] please.

Comment: @LuckyLikey Thanks alot for your kind response. I am using c++ in visual studio, I need to access sqlite database and display its contents using Qtableview or qtable widget. I have no idea how to do this...  I hope im much clear now

Comment: well i hope you'll get an answer. But be aware, that writing a good question will also get you better answers for it. Maybe this guideline helps you: [How to Write the perfect Question?](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: The Qt documentation is some of  the best there is. The answer to your question is here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-presenting.htmlhttp://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-presenting.html